# Btrfs snapshot create error "Text file busy"

Tags: linux, btrfs

Trying to create a read-only snapshot of the root subvolume using

```
sudo btrfs sub snap -r /mnt/@ /mnt/@_20200510
```

leads to error message

```
Create a readonly snapshot of '/mnt/@' in '/mnt/@_20200510'
ERROR: cannot snapshot '/mnt/@': Text file busy
```

Also, snapper and other backup tools stopped working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn off and delete the swapfile.

Linux 5.x introduced official swapfile support for Btrfs. Unfortunately, this support appears to be, ahem, incomplete. I suppose what is happening is that a subvolume which contains an open non-COW file cannot be snapshotted (snapshot? snapfleshwounded?). On some level this makes complete sense. On another, wtf. sigh.

If you want to use a swapfile, I think it should be fine to create a separate subvolume, however I have not tested this. Otherwise, you really do need to delete the swapfile before making the snapshot otherwise the file will get reflinked, stop being non-COW even though you marked it as such, and swapon won't work.

Comment: Creating a separate subvolume is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206161), and works for me under Ubuntu 21.04 with 5.11 kernel.

Comment: Also, running 'sudo swapoff -a' before taking a snapshot does the trick just as well. Follow up with 'sudo swapon -a' to re-enable the swap.